# Devise authentication when accessing directly to a pdf file unauthenticated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a problem when trying to see a .pdf file (generated with PDFKit) unauthenticated, just going directly from a given url `host/.../profile.pdf`. I, as expected, am asked to enter the credentials as shown in the image (Not in the users/sign_in path):

[image: asking for authentication]

I enter the correct credentials, the box goes up and down and asks for the credentials again. It could seem like the user or password are wrong, but they aren't. The relevant code from the controller is here:

```
class Entrepreneur::ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    respond_to do |format|
      format.pdf do
        html = render_to_string(:layout => false , :action => "show.html.haml")
        kit = PDFKit.new(html)
        send_data(kit.to_pdf, :filename => "name.pdf", :type => 'application/pdf')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Nothing fancy as you can see. I tried to remove the show action from the filter (`before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show]`) and write myself a custom filter to redirect unauthenticated users to new_session_path, but doing so I don't know how to, once signed up, redirect the user to the pdf show.

In short, devise asks for my credentials when accessing a pdf show and doesn't accept them. How can I get the user to the sign_in page and redirect back to the pdf once signed?

I'm using Rails 3.0.7, Ruby 1.8.7 and Devise 1.1.5.

Thanks!

Comment: Why does a box pop up? `before_filter :authenticate_user!` is supposed to redirect you to the login page, isn't it? Did you change something?

Comment: You'll need to show the code where you authenticate the user.

Comment: @Robin, nope, nothing changed

Comment: @draevor, Devise handles that, I didn't change devise's functionality.

Comment: @Robin, And yes, it's supposed and it does it in any other case, but not when directly accessing a PDF.

Comment: It works when already logged in and you try to access the pdf?

Comment: Ok... And if you're logged out, then try to access the pdf, enter the credentials that are supposed to work, and finally go back to other pages of the site, are you logged in?

Comment: You could get a local version of the devise gem, and try to find out where it's going wrong...

Comment: @Robin, Nope, the alert box goes up and down and asks for the credentials again. Then, if I click cancel (Or open a new tab) and go to the application, I'm not logged in. And about messing around with the gem, well, that's something I'm trying to avoid :P Anyway, I'll have to do that if I don't find any solution first. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, make sure that it's actually Rails serving the PDF and not a web server in front of it. (Depending on your configuration, it could be the request is never getting to Rails in the first place.)

Assuming it is Rails serving the file, then you should check your devise.rb configuration file. You may need to make :pdf a navigational format which will allow Devise to issue a 302 redirect to your sign_in page:

`config.navigational_formats = [:html, :pdf] # you may have additional formats`

Also, you may need to add PDF to your mime_types.rb initializer if it's not there already:

`Mime::Type.register 'application/pdf', :pdf`

Comment: Thanks Chris! Rails was actually serving (Or trying to) the PDF, and adding pdf to devises navigational_formats works! Good to know that :D (I need 3 more hours to award the bounty)

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem! But, now devise is redirect me to /users/sign_in.pdf.  Is there any way I can drop that .pdf from sign_in path?

Comment: Well, I found a solution to my own question: override skip_format? method in custom_failure.rb (<= search stackoverflow for more about this).  The method body look like this: $w(html pdf */*).include? request_format.to_s

Answer (score 4):

Adding to the accepted answer and repeating for completeness:

Update your devise config (`config/initializers/devise.rb`) to include pdf as a `navigational_format`.

Also update your devise config to use a custom `failure_app`.

```
require 'custom_failure'

Devise.setup do |config|
  # Navigate on pdf request types (i.e. .pdf)
  config.navigational_formats = ["*/*", :html, :pdf]

  config.warden do |manager|
    # Custom app to redirect to login page on unauthenticated pdf request types
    manager.failure_app = CustomFailure
  end
end
```

Custom failure app (`lib/custom_failure.rb`)

```
class CustomFailure < Devise::FailureApp

  # Redirect pdf request types to the login page
  def skip_format?
    %w(html pdf */*).include? request_format.to_s
  end

end
```

Comment: This is perfect answer, it is very useful to me.